# Define a DerivedClass::BaseClass obj; does not work

Tags: c++

I am a beginner of c++. I am learning a text on lookup names(or parsing).
I define a instance by "Derived::Base obj" in code below. But the obj does not have a void print() function of Base class. It is strange for me. Or I misunderstand the meaning of "Derived::Base obj".
If someone can tell me what happens in the code. Please tell me it.

```
class Base {
public:
    void print(void) {
        std::cout << "Base::print()." << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

Derived::Base obj;
obj.print();  // Error!! Compiler gives me an error message "error: ‘obj’ does not name a type"
```

Comment: Use `Derived obj;` not `Derived::Base obj;`. In the latter `Base` is a nested class within the `Derived` class, which is not the case.

Comment: `obj.print();` can't appear outside any function scope. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You actually don't need MCVE for this question, error is obvious.

Comment: Thank you James Adkison. My text use Derived::Base obj; This line is strange for me but compiler does not make an error. To learned what happen in the code, I test a line obj.print(). But compiler judge it as an error. May be "Derived::Base obj;" is just an example but it is not valid code. I am sorry for posting invalid code. I could not find it was invalid.

Comment: @Zereges: Not the point. The requirement for an MCVE is only partially for comprehensibility. The rest is because question authors **MUST** learn this skill and become accustomed to forming an MCVE _before_ posting. Otherwise, they have done insufficient debugging on their own time before requesting ours. It's the only weapon we have left in this sad sad world in which people post on SO before actually trying to fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this:

```
 Derived::Base obj;
```

to create object of derived class, just use:

```
 Derived d;
 d.print();
```

(from the comments): the reason compiler didnt gave you any error while:

```
 Derived::Base obj;
```

because, it created Base object, instead of derived object.

you can test that, by making similar function in derived class:

```
void print(void) {
    std::cout << "Derived::print()." << std::endl;
}
```

and:

```
Derived d;
d.print();

Derived::Base obj;

obj.print();
```